# Order by collection using linq by fields at deep level class/entity

Tags: c#, linq

I have following entity structure. I have couple of decorator which will populate the Invoice.InvoiceLines and at end I want to order those invoicelines by OrderReference

```
 public class Invoice 
    {
        private readonly IList<InvoiceLine> _invoiceLines;
        public virtual IList<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines => _invoiceLines;

        public Invoice()
        {
            _invoiceLines = new List<InvoiceLine>();
        }

    }

    public class InvoiceLine 
    {

        private readonly IList<TransactionLine> _transactionLines = new List<TransactionLine>();
        public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<TransactionLine> TransactionLines => new ReadOnlyCollection<TransactionLine>(_transactionLines);

        public virtual void AddTransactionLine(TransactionLine transactionLine)
        {
            transactionLine.ThrowIfNull(nameof(transactionLine), "can't be null");
            _transactionLines.Add(transactionLine);
        }
    }


    public class PermanentPlacementTransactionLine : TransactionLine
    {

        public PermanentPlacement PermanentPlacement { get; set; }
    }


      public  class PermanentPlacement 
    {
        public virtual string JobReference { get; set; }
        public virtual string OrderReference { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is order invoice lines by OrderReference.

```
  foreach (var invoice in DecoratedResult.Invoices.Where(inv => inv.InvoiceType == InvoiceType.Weekly))
            {
                var customer = CustomerRepository.FetchByAccountNumber(invoice.CustomerAccountNumber);
                if (customer.InvoiceProperties.InvoiceSequence == InvoiceSequence.OrderReference)
                {
                   // order by fields at deep level.
                   // invoice.InvoiceLines.OrderBy(i => i.TransactionLines.OfType<PermanentPlacementTransactionLine>());
                }
            }
```

I could expose properties to invoiceline and then set accordingly but is there any way I could do it using linq.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b and you'll find an OrderBy method.

Comment: Is the problem that whenever you add new items to your list you want them they are going on the end and thus the list stops being sorted? If so `SortedList ` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)  may be of interest to you. Otherwise I'm a little unsure of where your problem actually is.

Comment: I've noticed that it looks like only some of your `TransactionLine` objects (those of type `PermanentPlacementTransactionLine`) have the OrderReference on them. What do you want to do with other types of TransactionLine? You need to specify this better...

Comment: So to be clear, you want to sort just `invoice.InvoiceLines` and not `DecoratedResult.Invoices`, correct?

Comment: @Chris yes for other type of transaction line I will have different field to order on.

Comment: @Vikhram yes just invoiceLines in Invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was managed to do following way

```
     invoiceLines.OrderBy(Func1)
     //.ThenBy(Func2).
     //ThenBy(Func3).
     ToList();

private static string Func1(InvoiceLine invoiceLine) =>
            invoiceLine.TransactionLines.OfType<PermanentPlacementTransactionLine >().First()
                .OrderReference ;
```